# How to include Angular app selections in share link

Tags: angularjs, share

Suppose I select features in an Angular driven shopping cart, or similar example. I.e... a large size, color red, made of cotton.

How would I include these product changes in the a share link?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more of an application question rather then just an Angular question, but you could include those attributes in the query string.

www.mysite.com/products?color=red&size=large&material=cotton

In angular you can get set the query string like this:

```
function AppCtrl($scope, $location) {
    $scope.qs = $location.search();

    $scope.color = $scope.qs.color;
}
```

This would return an object with all of the query string items.
To set the query string you can do.

```
function AppCtrl($scope, $location) {
    $scope.setQs = function(size, color) {
        $location.search('size', size);
        $location.search('color', color);
    }
}
```

Your controller can serve up the item based on those query strings so when you share the link out you can send those attributes as well. Hope this helps.